# Excel VBA | How to prevent a click-event to be triggered upon initialize

Tags: excel, vba

Cell editing on my worksheet is done through an UF.
Upon selecting a cell, the cell value is shown in a combobox on the UF.

Selecting a range of cells and clicking on another item in the combobox will populate the selected range with the newly chosen item from the Combobox.

The problem starts with the selecting of multiple cells.
For some reason the click-event is triggered and all selected cells are populated with value of the first selected cell in the range.

Most probably because the initialize-event determines the first selected cells value, looks if it is found in the combobox-list, and if it is, it will show that value in the combobox.
It seems that showing the selected cell-value in the combobox triggers the click-event and will therefore populate all selected cells with that value.

The same goes for option buttons on the UF.
Some values are not in the combobox list, for example the value "OFF"
Selecting a cell with the value "OFF" will switch the option button to true.
but again, if more than one cell is selected, of which the first selected cell has the value "OFF", all other selected cells will take the same value.

the initialize event has for example the following line of code:

```
If ActiveCell.Value = "OFF" Then OptionButton1.Value = True
```

the click-event of the option button is as follows:

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
    OptionButton1.Value = True
    For Each C In Selection
        C.Value = "OFF"
    Next
End Sub
```

The question is, how do I prevent the click-event to be triggered upon initialize?

update:

```
Public Sub UserForm_Initialize() 
If Selection.Cells.Count > 1 Then
    OptionButton1.Value = False
    OptionButton2.Value = False
    OptionButton3.Value = False
    OptionButton4.Value = False
    ComboBox1.ListIndex = -1
    TextBox3.Text = ""
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    Exit Sub
End If

Me.ComboBox1.Clear
For Each Item In Sheets("MISC").Range("UNIQUESHIFTS")
    myRange = Replace(Item.Value, ";", " | ")
    Me.ComboBox1.AddItem myRange
Next Item

Me.ComboBox2.Clear
For Each Item In Sheets("ROSTERS").Range("Rosters")
    Me.ComboBox2.AddItem Item.Value
Next Item

OptionButton1.Value = False
OptionButton2.Value = False
OptionButton3.Value = False
OptionButton4.Value = False
If ActiveCell.Value = "OFF" Then OptionButton1.Value = True
If ActiveCell.Value = "SICK" Then OptionButton2.Value = True
If ActiveCell.Value = "TRAINING" Then OptionButton3.Value = True
If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then OptionButton4.Value = True

On Error Resume Next
Dim l As Long
MyCell = Replace(ActiveCell.Value, Chr(10), ";")
l = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(MyCell, Sheets("MISC").Range("UNIQUESHIFTS"), 0)
ComboBox1.ListIndex = l - 1

If InStr(ActiveCell.Value, "-") > 0 Then
    TextBox3.Text = Split(ActiveCell.Value, Chr(10))(0)
    TextBox1.Text = Right(Split(ActiveCell.Value, "-")(0), 4)
    TextBox2.Text = Left(Split(ActiveCell.Value, "-")(1), 4)
Else
    TextBox3.Text = ""
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    TextBox2.Text = ""
End If

On Error Resume Next
TextBox4.Value = ""
TextBox4.Value = ActiveCell.Comment.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: Clicking an option button will always make it's value = True.  This line is not needed: `OptionButton1.Value = True` .  You can avoid your loop and just use `Selection.Value  = "OFF"`.

Comment: Your Click event code isn't related to your issue.  Can you [edit your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39746311/edit) to include the code for your initialization?